# MATLAB: varargin acting differently from 'real' cell array?

Tags: matlab, variadic-functions

Is varargin exactly the same as a cell array?

I have a simple varargin parser in my test class as shown here:

```
classdef MySuperClass
properties(Access = protected)
    superPropA = (1:4);
    superPropB = 'superBar';
end

methods
    % constructor
    function obj = MySuperClass(varargin)
        % check varargins

        % required parameter
        arg = varargin(find(strcmp(varargin, 'SuperA'))+1);
        if ~isempty(arg) && isnumeric(arg{1}) && length(arg{1}) > 1
            obj.superPropA = arg{1};
        else
            newExc = MException('SubClass:Constructor:InputParser',...
                'Expected numeric vector argument for SuperA');
            throw(newExc);
        end

        % optional parameter
        if any(strcmp(varargin, 'SuperB'))
            arg = varargin(find(strcmp(varargin, 'SuperB'))+1);
            if ~isempty(arg)
                obj.superPropB = arg{1};
            else
                newExc = MException('SubClass:Constructor:InputParser',...
                    'Expected argument for SuperB');
                throw(newExc);
            end
        end

        % output varargins
        fprintf('SuperClass:\nSuper property A: %s\nSuper property B: %s', obj.superPropA, obj.superPropB);
    end
end
end
```

When I instantiate the class with `SubInst = MySubClass('SuperA', (1:5), 'SuperB', 'Hello')` from my subclass

```
function obj = MySubClass(varargin)
            % call super class constructor
            obj = obj@SuperClassModules.MySuperClass(varargin);
...
```

to call the constructor of the superclass with the parser, then arg is {} (see first code block), which it should not from my understanding.

Because when I type in the console:

```
>> a = {'SuperA', (1:5), 'SuperB', 'Hello'}

a = 

    'SuperA'    [1x5 double]    'SuperB'    'Hello'

>> arg = a(find(strcmp(a, 'SuperA'))+1)

arg = 

    [1x5 double]

>> arg{1}

ans =

     1     2     3     4     5
```

it works as expected.

Why does it not work inside the constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To simplify I will forget about all the class stuff when explaining the issue. You have a function `foo(varargin)` and `bar(varargin)`

If you now call `foo(1,2,3)` it get's called with `varargin={1,2,3}`. If you now want to call `bar(1,2,3)` inside `foo` you can't simply use `bar(varargin)`, that would be `bar({1,2,3})`. Instead you have to call `bar` using a comma separated list: `bar(varargin{:})`. This unpacks the elements of the cell array to `1,2,3` resulting in the call you want.

In your code it would be:

```
obj = obj@SuperClassModules.MySuperClass(varargin{:});
```